# Strip certain querystring values (but not all) from a url using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

As an extension of a previous post I have the following url:

`test/example/example/index.html?t=Audi&p=Petrol`

but I would like a rewrite rule to strip out the query-string **t** and **p**. Note that there may be other querystring values that may be passed and these should not be stripped.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
# First remove the t=something
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)(^|&)t=[^&]+(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1%3 [N]

# Next remove the p=something
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)(^|&)p=[^&]+(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1%3 [L]
```

So going to `http://domain/test/example/example/index.html?a=b&t=fooo&d=f&p=barr&e=r` will result in the URI getting rewritten to: `/test/example/example/index.html?a=b&amp;d=f&amp;e=r`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

`RewriteRule ^/(.*)\&t=[a-zA-Z]+(.+)$ %1%2 [L]`

Or use some `RewriteCond` if you need to collect that params, ie. though ENV.

Comment: Well "Something like this:" will not work as RewriteRule does NOT work with query string like that -- only via RewriteCond.